# moment().format() and fullcalendar: undefined is not a function

Tags: fullcalendar, momentjs

I'm trying to use moment().format() with fullcalendar; I have this code:

```
<script src="<?php echo ASSETS_URL; ?>/js/plugin/fullcalendar/lib/moment.js"></script>
<script> moment().format() </script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

        header: hdr,
        buttonText: {
            prev: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>',
            next: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>'
        },
        defaultView: "agendaWeek",
        editable: true,
        droppable: false, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar !!!
        lang: 'it',
        timeFormat: 'H(:mm)',
        firstDay: 1,
        drop: function (date, allDay) { // this function is called when something is dropped


        events: [{

        }],
        eventDragStart: function( event, jsEvent, ui, view ) { 
            ev_start=event.start.moment().format("dddd (d) DDD - D/MM/YY");
            console.log(ev_start);
            },

        },
```

When I drag an element from calendar there is this error:
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

I done some debug and the error is caused by moment().format()
Anyone could help me?

Comment: you don't need that line at all.
<script> moment().format() </script>

Comment: Also without the line there is the error..

Comment: Try removing your lib and using this CDN: <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.2/moment.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you receive that error on that line, check your moment.js file is good.

Then, this line is wrong:

```
ev_start=event.start.moment().format("dddd (d) DDD - D/MM/YY");
```

If `event.start` it's a `timedate` you should do this:

```
ev_start = moment(event.start).format("dddd (d) DDD - D/MM/YY");
```

Comment: ok it works! using this sintax I've resolved the problem. Thank you very much Michele :)